# How to search string for a specific substring and get a number associated with that substring?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

I am a newbie learning C# and this is the task at hand:  I have a text file with a some JSON in it. In the text file there are multiple lines and each paragraph is separated from the next through an empty line.

I want to get the number associated with the substring "Label " + number. See below.

This is an example of the input from the text file:

> {"menu": {"header": "menu", "items": [{"id": 27}, {"id": 0, "label": "Label 0"}, null, {"id": 93}, {"id": 85}, {"id": 54}, null, {"id": 46, "label": "Label 46"}]}}
>
> {"menu": {"header": "menu", "items": [{"id": 81}]}}
>
> {"menu": {"header": "menu", "items": [{"id": 70, "label": "Label 70"},
> {"id": 85, "label": "Label 85"}, {"id": 93, "label": "Label 93"},
> {"id": 2}]}}

What I've done so far is:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string path = @"C:\Users\X\Desktop\docomentul.txt";
        string jSONstring;

        string resultString;
        string labelString = "Label ";


        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            jSONstring = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var jSONlines = Regex.Split(jSONstring,"(?m)^\\s*$");

            
            foreach (var line in jSONlines)
            {
                resultString = Regex.Match(line, @"\d+").Value;
                Console.WriteLine(resultString);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Now this only brings back the first occurrence of a number in the string. What I want is to find each occurrence of the numbers associated with the substring "Label ". At least that is how I planned on solving this. However I don't really know how to use REGEX nor how to find it in another way.

Once I get the numbers associated with the substring "Label ", I will have to add them for each item and then print out the sum for each string in the array (or paragraph).

The output for the test input should be:
46
0
248

Comment: I wouldn't parse JSON with Regex. There are plenty of good parsers already available for .NET. Try Newtonsoft.Json. Then you'll have a list of objects that you can iterate over or use LINQ on.

Comment: That may be overkill for this task, since it is an easy task on a coding challenge website that I'm trying to practice on. I was hoping there would be an easier way to search the string for what I need. Or an alternative solution. Using that framework won't get me to pass the challenge since the computer that will be compiling the code won't recognize it in the online editor.

Comment: Have you tried in your loop `Regex.Matches(line, @"Label \d+");` and then iterated through each match to add your label numbers up by using `match.Value.Split(' ').Last();`?

Comment: This is definitively a pointer in the right direction as i get back a group of strings in the form "Label + number". From here I will def get the final result.

Comment: Another way I just thought of would be to simply split each string on "Label " using string.Split and that would have gotten me an array of strings starting with my number. I'll try to solve it with both methods and see where it takes me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string json = YOUR_JSON_STRING;
        string[] arrayStrings = json.Split("Label ");
        List<int> lst = new List<int>();
        foreach (string str in arrayStrings)
        {
            lst.Add(Convert.ToInt16(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("\"") - 1)));
        }
        //lst now contains all the numbers for you!
```

Keep coding!